# In Angular 5 testing, how to mock an http error?

Tags: angular

I am doing unit test in Angular 5.

With the new http module, I know that I can mock response data by using `flush` method in `HttpTestingController`, but how can I mock an error (I want to test my error handler)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `error` rather than `flush`

```
httpTestingController.expectOne(url).error(errorEvent);
```

or pass a status to flush:

```
httpTestingController.expectOne(url).flush(null, {status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request"});
```