# Jasmine spec has no expectations (when there are)

Tags: angular, jasmine

I know there are some similar questions but couldn't find one to solve my issue.

So I have the following test (with 6 expectations):

```
  it('should redirect to error page when there is a 403 error', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockError403Response: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
      error: '403 error',
      status: 403,
      statusText: 'Forbidden'
    });

    httpClient.get("/v1/test").subscribe(_ => { },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        expect(error).toBeTruthy();
        expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/error', 403]);
        expect(error.status).toEqual(mockError403Response.status);
        expect(error.error).toContain(mockError403Response.error);
        expect(error.statusText).toContain(mockError403Response.statusText);
      });

    let request: TestRequest;
    request = httpTestingController.expectOne("/v1/test");
    request.flush(mockError403Response);
    tick(500);
  }));
```

And I get the warning:

```
Spec 'should redirect to error page when there is a 403 error' has no expectations.
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking, it never goes inside of your error block in your subscribe.

You have to pass a 2nd object for an error response in the `flush`. Right now, your test will go into the `_ => { }` of the subscribe block.

Try this:

```
 it('should redirect to error page when there is a 403 error', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockError403Response: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
      error: '403 error',
      status: 403,
      statusText: 'Forbidden'
    });

    httpClient.get("/v1/test").subscribe(_ => { 
       // Call Jasmine fail to ensure if it comes here, the test is a failure.
       // Before your test was traversing here.
       fail(); 
    },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // ensure you see this log.
        console.log('!! Making assertions !!');
        expect(error).toBeTruthy();
        expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/error', 403]);
        expect(error.status).toEqual(mockError403Response.status);
        expect(error.error).toContain(mockError403Response.error);
        expect(error.statusText).toContain(mockError403Response.statusText);
      });

    let request: TestRequest;
    request = httpTestingController.expectOne("/v1/test");
    // modify this line
    request.flush(mockError403Response, { status: 403, statusText: 'Forbidden' });
    tick(500);
  }));
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48143330/7365461) out on how to mock an Http error.